# How to fix .addEventListener button that validates username/password using Regex expressions

Tags: javascript, html

This is for a practice project I'm doing as a beginning learner. I'm attempting to call a function that validates user info when the submit button is clicked. The function must:

1. Takes two arguments representing username and password.
2. Checks the username and password match what is stored.
3. Checks that the password contains at least 8 characters, at least one letter, one number, and one special character.

Using regular expressions I think I have a function, validateInfo(), that matches the string inputs from my input elements against these expressions, checks that they match what is on file, and stores the associated errors in my errorArray[].

I previously had a value set in the html inputs, but was instructed by someone that they may have been causing the function to read the set values, so I've removed those.

My script tag is located at the end of my `</body>` tag, I've read that causes similar issues.

I suspect it may be my using else if, but trying to console.log(loginUser); or other values also does not work, so perhaps there's an issue with the values being stored.

Instead of pushing errors to my array, I tried a simple alert, but this fails also (unless it's when you first open the page, then you get the alert). <- This seems to yell at me.. but I don't know what's wrong...

```
HMTL:

<form id="loginForm">
      <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName"><br>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="pass"><br><br>
      <button id="loginBtn">Login</button><br>
</form>
...
<script src="PasswordPractice.js"></script>


JavaScript:

let regAlpha = /[a-z]+/i;
let regNum = /[0-9]+/;
let specChar = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/;  

let errorArray = [];

let username = "TestUser";
let passwordOne = "!validpassword1"

let loginUser = document.getElementById("userName").value;
let loginPass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
let loginBtn = document.getElementById("loginBtn");
loginBtn.addEventListener("click", validateInfo(loginUser, loginPass)); 

function validateInfo(loginUser, loginPass) {
    if (loginUser == "" || loginPass == "") {
        alert("Password or username is empty!"); // Does not work. 
    } else if (loginPass.length < 8) {          
        errorArray.push("Your password must be 8 characters or longer.");
    } else if (!loginPass.match(regAlpha)) {
        errorArray.push("Password must contain at least one letter.");
    } else if (!loginPass.match(regNum)) {
        errorArray.push("Password must contain at least one number. ");
    } else if (!loginPass.match(specChar)) {
        errorArray.push("Password must contain at least one special character.");
        alert(errorArray);
    } else if (errorArray.length > 0) {   
        alert(errorArray.join("\n")); 
    } else if (loginUser !== username) {
        alert("Error: Username not recognized.");
    } else if (loginPass !== passwordOne) {
        alert("Error: Incorrect password.");
    } else {
        alert("Welcome back, " + username);
        //window.location.href= 'profile.html'; For redirection to profile page
    }
}

// None of these work.
console.log(errorArray);
console.log(loginUser);
console.log(loginPass)
```

I realize there is an issue with my errorArray[] display, but my primary issue is my function. It seems to be called as soon at the page loads, and does not work when I click the submit button. There are no errors in the console. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does it HAVE to take 2 parameters?

Comment: Do you have the username/password available in the script?? ...that is wide open for anyone to break through

Answer (score 0):

Get your element values i.e. loginUser, loginPass within validateInfo function. Else loginUser, loginPass values will remain static after page load. Change it to -

```
loginBtn.addEventListener("click", validateInfo);
function validateInfo() {
  let loginUser = document.getElementById("userName").value;
  let loginPass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  .... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because you are already executing the function validateInfo when you call it with parentheses ,just replace that line by `loginBtn.addEventListener("click", validateInfo);`